# Delete all columns in which all rows have a value below 10000

Tags: r

I have a big dataset (2300 obs x 9700 var) in which I only want to have all variables (columns) in which all samples (rows) have a values above `10000`. 
I tried a lot of codes, for example:

```
subset <- df[,apply(df,1,function(z) !all(z<10000))]  
subset<- df[,df> 10000]
```

But they are not working. `RowMeans` doesn't work since maybe the mean is `< 10000` but some individual row may be `>10000`.

Anybody some tips how to tackle this?

Comment: Your condition is not clear.  In your code you are looping through the rows to find the rows that have all values less than 10000.  Then that is used for subsetting columns?  which is not of the correct length as your rows.  Perhaps you should use `df[apply(df, 1, .....),]`  If it is to delete columns that have all value below 10000, then `df[!sapply(df, function(x) all(x < 10000))]`

Answer (score 1):

Try this to filter out all rows in which all values are `>10000`:

```
df[rowSums(df>10000)==ncol(df),]

#      a      b     c
#4 14139 127746 10911
#7 11582  73952 10821
```

To filter out all columns in which all values are `>10000`:

```
df[,colSums(df>10000)==nrow(df)]

# [1]  40004 105808  70261 127746  60177 134365  73952  86584  87551  67781
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(a = c(13773, 8680, 4854, 14139, 3106, 3044, 11582, 
9475, 728, 4666), b = c(40004, 105808, 70261, 127746, 60177, 
134365, 73952, 86584, 87551, 67781), c = c(1913, 2092, 14468, 
10911, 14414, 8015, 10821, 12636, 12320, 1266)), .Names = c("a", 
"b", "c"), row.names = c(NA, -10L), class = "data.frame")

       # a      b     c
# 1  13773  40004  1913
# 2   8680 105808  2092
# 3   4854  70261 14468
# 4  14139 127746 10911
# 5   3106  60177 14414
# 6   3044 134365  8015
# 7  11582  73952 10821
# 8   9475  86584 12636
# 9    728  87551 12320
# 10  4666  67781  1266
```